# out of line definition of guided constructor (c++20)

Tags: c++, constructor, c++20, requires-clause

g++ happily accepts the following code, whereas clang nor msvc are able to match out of line definitions.

Any idea why ?

```
template <bool B>
struct test 
{
    test() requires (B);
    test() requires(!B);
};


template <>
test<true>::test()
{}

template <>
test<false>::test()
{}

int main()
{
    test<false> a;
    test<true> b;
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vYc18jh11)

Clang:

> error: out-of-line definition of '`test`' does not match any declaration in '`test<true>`'

Msvc:

> error C2244: '`test<true>::test`': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Comment: I would be very tempted to say that you don't need the constraints since you're specializing the constructor anyway.

Answer (score 6):

You're declaring constrained constructors but defining two unconstrained specializations. Those won't ever match.

What you probably meant was:

```
template <bool B>
struct test
{
    test() requires (B);
    test() requires(!B);
};

template <bool B>
test<B>::test() requires (B)
{}

template <bool B>
test<B>::test() requires (!B)
{}
```

This compiles fine in all 3 compilers.

As to why your original version compiles - it's a GCC bug [96830](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96830). Clang is right, code is ill-formed because the out-of-line definitions don't match the template definition (note also that `template<> ...` is *full specialization* syntax).

See [[temp.class.general]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.over.link#6) (emphasis mine):

> When a member of a class template is defined outside of the class template definition, the member definition is defined as a template definition with the *template-head* ***equivalent*** to that of the class template.

[[temp.over.link]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.over.link#6):

> Two *template-heads* are ***equivalent*** if their *template-parameter-lists* have the same length, corresponding *template-parameters* are equivalent and are both declared with *type-constraints* that are equivalent if either *template-parameter* is declared with a *type-constraint*, and ***if either *template-head* has a requires-clause, they both have requires-clauses and the corresponding constraint-expressions are equivalent***.

Also see [[temp.mem.func]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.class#temp.mem.func-1) for an example of declaring a constrained member out-of-line:

```
template<typename T> struct S {
    void f() requires C<T>;
    void g() requires C<T>;
};

template<typename T>
void S<T>::f() requires C<T> { }      // OK
template<typename T>
void S<T>::g() { }                    // error: no matching function in S<T>
```

Comment: How to fully specialize? adding `requires(true)` doesn't work neither [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/abzhTc1hn).

Comment: @Jarod42 according to [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.constr.decl#4) it should compile. So maybe neither compiler supports it yet?

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. The full specialization did not work, and it was not easy finding documentation on the subject. Full specialization (without require) worked with gcc probably because final (mangled) symbols matched....